# Replacing with different values based on numerical or alphabetical

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Below is a simplified version of the df in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['1_2_abc_def','34_567','8_910_ghi','11_12jkl']})

df

       col
0   1_2_abc_def
1   34_567
2   8_910_ghi
3   11_12jk
```

`col` contains string values. When the `_` separates numbers, I would like it to be replaced with `.`, and when the `_` separates letters or numbers and letters, I would like it to be replaced with a space.

Intended df:

```
        col
0   1.2 abc def
1   34.567
2   8.910 ghi
3   11.12jkl
```

Please note that all other unmentioned cases require the ‘_’ to be replaced with a space.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the comment of HenryEcker below my answer, please? At the end, do all '_' should be replaced or only your 2 specific cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative: use `replace` instead of `str.replace` like this:

```
>>> df.replace({'col': {r'(\d)_(\d)': r'\1.\2', r'_': ' '}}, regex=True)

           col
0  1.2 abc def
1       34.567
2    8.910 ghi
3     11.12jkl
```

With this method, you can use nested dictionary to replace values. As `dict` are now ordered (or use `defaultdict`), you can use it as as a sequence of ordered operations on strings. First, all occurrence of 'digit_digit' will be replaced by 'digit.digit' then all remaining '_' will be replaced by ' '.

Comment: Also makes the assumption that all `'_'` will have to be replaced (which is true for OP's example).

Comment: Maybe `r'([^\W_])_([^\W_])': r'\1 \2'` ?

Comment: @HenryEcker. I understand your regex but I don't know why it should replace `_': ' '`. Do I miss a use case? Can you explain me if you have time?

Comment: "when the _ separates letters or numbers and letters, I would like it to be replaced with a space" That would mean something like `._.` or `?_!` should not be replaced unless I'm misunderstanding the OP.

Comment: @HenryEcker. Thanks!. I asked to OP to check your comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex with lookahead for that:

```
df['col'].replace({'_(?=\D)': ' ', '_(?=\d)': '.'}, regex=True)
```

explanation: If non digit (`\D`) followed by '_', replace with space, else if digit (`\d`) followed by `_`, replace with `.`.

or

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('_(?=\d)', '.').str.replace('_', ' ')
```

or

```
df['col'].str.replace('_(?=\D)', ' ').str.replace('_', '.')
```

pandas > 1.1, the `regex=True` option needs to be specified to avoid the warning:

```
df['col'].str.replace('_(?=\D)', ' ', regex=True).str.replace('_', '.', regex=True)
```

Comment: update your Pandas version. For newest version, `str.replace` raises a FutureWarning if you don't add `regex=True`: `FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.`

Comment: Yes, that's right, thanks @Corralien , I added a comment on that (although not everyone is using latest version)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `<digit>_<digit>` first, then `<letter_or_digit>_<letter_or_digit>`.

```
df['col'].str.replace('(\d)_(\d)', r'\1.\2').str.replace('([aA-zZ]|\d)_([aA-zZ]|\d)', r'\1 \2')
```

Comment: IMHO this is unnecessarily verbose, there is no need to catch and restore.

Comment: @mozway this kind of depends on what assumptions you make about the strings that could be contained in the df. For OP's specific example you're correct.